# Как найти два элемента в одном списке

Tags: python

Есть метод, который принимает список, в котором 2 элемента. Я их достаю по индексу и задача такая найти их в другом списке. Я написал вот такое непотребство. Есть ли способ сделать это проще для поиска двух слов в одном списке?

```
unpack_list = [['Даша', 'Цветкова', '32', 'd@gmail.com', '3467746'], 
['Женя', 'Ромашкин', '34', 'kv@gmail.com', '2211133']]

arg = ['Женя', 'Ромашкин'] # найти эти два слова в unpack_list


  def two_words(self,arg):
    arg1 = arg[0]
    arg2 = arg[1]
    for i in self.unpack_list:
        for word in i:
            print('word',word)
            if arg1 in word:
                print('_here is something_',i)
            if arg2 in word:
                    print('_Here is Something_',i)
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста примеры первого и второго списка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё очень легко - необходимы два действия - пробежаться по списку и проверить условие вхождения "вашей" пары в элемент (с помощью множеств):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
arg = ['Женя', 'Ромашкин']

unpack_list = [['Даша', 'Цветкова', '32', 'd@gmail.com', '3467746'],
['Женя', 'Ромашкин', '34', 'kv@gmail.com', '2211133']]


for i in unpack_list:
    if set(i).issuperset(set(arg)):
        print i
```

Также для условия вхождения множества в множества возможен вариант через операторы: `set(arg) <= set(i)`

Answer (score 3):

```
arg = ['Женя', 'Ромашкин']

unpack_list = [['Даша', 'Цветкова', '32', 'd@gmail.com', '3467746'],
['Женя', 'Ромашкин', '34', 'kv@gmail.com', '2211133']]

class A():
    def __init__(self, list1, list2):
        self.list1 = list1
        self.list2 = list2

    def two_words(self):
        for i in self.list2:
            if self.list1[0] in i:
                if self.list1[1] in i:
                    print('_Here is Something_', i)


a = A(arg, unpack_list)

a.two_words()
_Here is Something_ ['Женя', 'Ромашкин', '34', 'kv@gmail.com', '2211133']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lst1 = [['Даша', 'Цветкова', '32', 'd@gmail.com', '3467746'], 
['Женя', 'Ромашкин', '34', 'kv@gmail.com', '2211133']]

lst2 = ['Женя', 'Ромашкин']
res=[x for x in lst1 if len(set(x)&set(lst2))==len(lst2)]
print(res)
```

> [['Женя', 'Ромашкин', '34', 'kv@gmail.com', '2211133']]

Если сделать генератор так:

```
res=[x for x in lst1 if set(x)&set(lst2)]
```

То будет выдан результат если совпало хотя бы одно слово, что тоже может быть полезным.